# jenkins test reports isn't contain Junit ParamterizedTest

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, junit5, parametrized-testing

I want to monitor the execution time of my test in `Jenkins`. but the report just contains any test with `test` annotation not, `@ParameterizedTest`. how can I see the execution time of `@ParameterizedTest` in the Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

the problem was related to `maven`, not Jenkins. by default `maven-failesafe-plugin` will load just `junit-engine` as a dependency and because `parametrized-test` is in another jar file, the problem came to view. so I just added it as a `dependency` to the `maven-failesafe-plugin`